# Is it possible to estimate the Hessian as the covariance of primal and cotangent?

Tags: fisher-information, point-estimation, hessian

Let's say we have a function

$$f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R.$$

Can we numerically approximate the Hessian $f''(x)$ as

$$\textrm{Var}(a)^{-1} \textrm{Cov}(a, f'(a))$$

where

$$E(a) = x?$$

Comment: Estimating the covariance would require say $30$ evaluations of the gradient $f'$ which may be more than for a finite difference. So the motivation is for $n$ large?

Comment: @Yves My motivation is that I want to estimate the diagonal entries of the Hessian as efficiently as possible.  Is there a way to do that efficiently with finite differences?  Please feel free to add an answer.